# How can i use unioan and nested from linq?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, linq

How can i convert to sql to linq . i don't understand nested select query. i need linq codes.  Please help me:((((

```
SELECT @id=id FROM 
    (SELECT id,workorder AS workorderno ,CAST(jobseqno AS int) AS jobseqno FROM dbo.CTask
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id,workorderno,cardno AS jobseqno FROM dbo.NonRoutineCard
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id,workorderno,cardno AS jobseqno FROM dbo.AdditionalWorkCard) a
WHERE RTRIM(workorderno)=RTRIM(@ToNo) AND jobseqno=@ToSeq
```

**LINQ:**

```
  var id = 
  (from task in stock.CTasks select new { task.id, task.workorder, task.jobseqno } )
  .Union(from card in stock.NonRoutineCards select new { card.id, card.workorderno, card.cardno })
  .Union(from card in stock.AdditionalWorkCards select new { card.id, card.workorderno, card.cardno })
  .Where(x => x.workorderno.TrimEnd() == ToNo && x.jobseqno == ToSeq)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

if i write above codes error below:

[image]

Comment: The SQL code joins multiple tables together:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/01/31/converting-sql-to-linq-part-8-left-right-outer-join-bill-horst.aspx
You should also do some specific reading on UNION ALL, don't know what it is but it must be some kind of join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will that suit your needs?

```
var id = 
  (from task in stock.CTasks select new { task.id, task.workorder, jobseqno= task.jobseqno } )
  .Union(from card in stock.NonRoutineCards select new { card.id, card.workorderno, jobseqno = card.cardno })
  .Union(from card in stock.AdditionalWorkCards select new { card.id, card.workorderno, jobseqno = card.cardno })
  .Where(x => x.workorderno.TrimEnd() == ToNo && x.jobseqno == ToSeq)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i add a picture and linq query

Comment: that's because one of your field is named 'jobseqno' while the same field in another subquery is 'cardno'. specify field name in both cases explicitly:
... new {task.ID, task.workorderno, Num = (int)task.jobseqno}
... new { card.ID, card.workorderno, Num = card.cardno }
... Where(... x.Num == ToSeq)

Comment: i just told you in my previous comment :)